# Attempting to calculate lat and long given distance and bearing from start point

Tags: c#, .net, gis, geospatial, latitude-longitude

Using [this](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) website I am trying to calculate a lat and long from an initial lat and long as well as a distance and bearing in C# but I can not get it to work correctly. The output seems to always stick near the equator more or less vertically in line with the start point no matter the bearing and distance. I have done what the website has said but to no success.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
    public static double[] LocWithBearingAndDistance(double lat, double lon, double bearing, double distanceM)
    {
        double angdistance = distanceM / 6371000.0;
        double lat2 = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Cos(angdistance) + Math.Cos(lat) * Math.Sin(angdistance) * Math.Cos(bearing));
        double lon2 = lon + Math.Atan2(Math.Cos(angdistance) - Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Sin(lat2), Math.Sin(bearing) * Math.Sin(angdistance) * Math.Cos(lat));
        return new double[2] {lat2, (lon2 + 540) % 360 - 180};
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code that solved the problem:

```
public static (double Lat, double Lon) Destination((double Lat, double Lon) startPoint, double distance, double bearing)
    {
        double φ1 = startPoint.Lat * (Math.PI / 180);
        double λ1 = startPoint.Lon * (Math.PI / 180);
        double brng = bearing * (Math.PI / 180);
        double φ2 = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(φ1) * Math.Cos(distance / radius) + Math.Cos(φ1) * Math.Sin(distance / radius) * Math.Cos(brng));
        double λ2 = λ1 + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(brng) * Math.Sin(distance / radius) * Math.Cos(φ1), Math.Cos(distance / radius) - Math.Sin(φ1) * Math.Sin(φ2));
        return (φ2 * (180 / Math.PI), λ2 * (180 / Math.PI));
    }
```

`radius` is the radius of the Earth in meters.